# How to verticaly center an html that was set as A4

Tags: html

I have this HTML that was set as an A4 in size. As you can see when you load it and zoom it out there is a lot of margin/space at the bottom.What do I need to change to have it vertically centered?

this is the sample HTML code

```css
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial;
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 20cm;
  height: 28.7cm;
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
  <table style="width:100%; height:100%; border: outset #B4CBF2 3pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0 50px 0 50px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="height:10%; border: outset #B4CBF2 1.0pt;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</page>
```

Below is a sample picture when you view it in a browser

[html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtMwx.png)

Comment: I doubt that someone is gonna be able to answer this without more context, What do you mean by there's a lot of margin if you zoom out? running your code i can see everything is vertically centered, even after zooming out

Comment: It's really not entirely clear what exactly you mean. Give more details, pls.

Comment: Where does this `<page>` element come from?

Comment: I edited my post, I added a photo(screen capture). Hope it helps

Comment: @DotDot checkout either smunteanu or my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that, So you should add jquery file into your page and also add these lines:

```js
  $(function() {
      $('page').css({
          'position' : 'absolute',
          'left' : '50%',
          'top' : '50%',
          'margin-left' : -$('page').width()/2,
          'margin-top' : -$('page').height()/2
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: adding jQuery to center an element?

Comment: Yes, why not? Do you know a better way?

Comment: what about pure css? and if we really want to use javascript does the 3 lines of jQuery you posted really justify pulling on the whole library as a dependency when you can just do the same using just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some edits. Now it works well.
You can do it by adding height to html and body and a flex display to the body. See the code below:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        *{
            height: max(100%,28.7cm);
            width:max(100%,20cm);
        }
        body{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        page {
          background: white;
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
          font-family: Arial;
        }

        page[size="A4"] {
          width: 20cm;
          height: 28.7cm; 
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <page size="A4">
    <table style="width:100%; height:100%; border: outset #B4CBF2 3pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0 50px 0 50px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height:10%; border: outset #B4CBF2 1.0pt;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </page>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the top border falls off the page in full screen mode. add `max-height: 100%` in `page[size = "A4"]`

Comment: The `page` height does not adjust to the screen height. I do not know if the author of the question needs this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML: add `class="center"` to the page opening tag

```
<page size="A4" class="center">
    ...
</page>
```

CSS: add `.center` to the code

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css grid, this is all you need

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: the top border is missing when I go to fullscreen mode(100%)

Comment: @DotDot a small padding might suffice in your case

Comment: Got it, it worked. I added some padding just like what you told

Comment: @DotDot glad it worked! It would be nice if you mark the answer that worked for you